# Facebook post wall sharing of google play link, can't show given description and name

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I'm trying to share a link and provide a description of the link to facebook through Android Apps, using facebook SDK

```
public void postToWall(View v){

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();    
        parameters.putString("name", "My App test");
        parameters.putString("description", "This is a test");
        parameters.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.barouch.whatsthemissingnumber&hl=en");

    ... ...

    });
}
```

However, me description and name doesn't come out, as it seemingly being obscured by the link. If I replace the link with a simple link (e.g. www.google.com), my description is now shown together with the name.

Is it true if we post a googleplay apps store link, we can't post our own description and name? Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: The name and description is fetched from the link. Tell google to add og-tags on the page

Comment: I am not sure whether Facebook now prioritzes OG data embedded in the page shared over custom parameters in general, or if that is maybe a special treatment of links to Google app store (because if have seen this type of question multiple times recently specifically about sharing Google app store links). It would make sense though, I think – to stop people from posting links to apps with fraudulent descriptions.